# Deploying a Process Builder results in error: The element has an invalid reference to "myVariable_current.RelatedToId"

Tags: process-builder, deployment

**Given**

- a Process Builder on `EmailMessage`
- that references a related parent object in an Update Records action element

  `[EmailMessage].Related To ID (Case)`

**When**

Deploying this Process Builder to another CI sandbox via our devops pipeline

**Then**

Deployment fails with error:

```
EmailMessage_Automation Flow    myRule_5_A1 (Update Records) - 
The element has an invalid reference to "myVariable_current.RelatedToId".
```

### Why would this be?

We've done over 3000 deployments into our CI org without this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, turns out this was the first time any of the development org Process Builders or Flows exploited the polymorphic parent relationship in [EmailMessage.RelatedToId](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.228.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm)

and, for whatever reason, the CI org did not have Enhanced Email enabled in Setup - which is what reveals the `RelatedToId` field on `EmailMessage`.